# R transpose in order to rearrange a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, data-wrangling

I have the following dataframe, 1 row and 31 columns and I want to change it to 2 columns and 31 rows. Those represent income per year from 1990 to 2020. Each column is the year 1990, 1991 ...

```
dput(head(china_income_30)

structure(list(`1990` = "1420", `1991` = "1540", `1992` = "1730", 
    `1993` = "1950", `1994` = "2180", `1995` = "2390", `1996` = "2600", 
    `1997` = "2810", `1998` = "3000", `1999` = "3210", `2000` = "3450", 
    `2001` = "3710", `2002` = "4020", `2003` = "4400", `2004` = "4820", 
    `2005` = "5340", `2006` = "5980", `2007` = "6800", `2008` = "7410", 
    `2009` = "8070", `2010` = "8890", `2011` = "9680", `2012` = "10.4k", 
    `2013` = "11.1k", `2014` = "11.9k", `2015` = "12.6k", `2016` = "13.4k", 
    `2017` = "14.2k", `2018` = "15.1k", `2019` = "16k", `2020` = "16.3k"), row.names = 33L, class = "data.frame")
```

I'm not happy with the process that I used to rearrange the data. How could I do better using base R?

```
d <- data.frame(t(china_income_30))
d$X33 <- as.numeric(gsub("k", "e3", d$X33))
d$year = rownames(d)
colnames(d) <- c('China', 'year')
row.names(d) <- NULL

head(d)
  China year
1  1420 1990
2  1540 1991
3  1730 1992
4  1950 1993
5  2180 1994
6  2390 1995
```

I'm open to using dplyr or some other library but I'm curious how would this look like using base R but in a proper fashion.

Comment: What you show in your first block doesn't fully look like a frame. Can you please use `dput(head(china_income_30))` to post your sample data?

Answer (score 3):

Using `dat` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end use `stack` to create 2 columns, set the names, replace k with e3 and then convert the columns to numeric using `type.convert`.  No packages are used.

```
dat |>
  stack() |>
  setNames(c("China", "year")) |>
  transform(China = sub("k", "e3", China)) |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
##    China year
## 1   1420 1990
## 2   1540 1991
## 3   1730 1992
## 4   1950 1993
## 5   2180 1994
## ...snip...
```

### Note

```
dat <- structure(list(`1990` = "1420", `1991` = "1540", `1992` = "1730", 
`1993` = "1950", `1994` = "2180", `1995` = "2390", `1996` = "2600", 
`1997` = "2810", `1998` = "3000", `1999` = "3210", `2000` = "3450", 
`2001` = "3710", `2002` = "4020", `2003` = "4400", `2004` = "4820", 
`2005` = "5340", `2006` = "5980", `2007` = "6800", `2008` = "7410", 
`2009` = "8070", `2010` = "8890", `2011` = "9680", `2012` = "10.4k", 
`2013` = "11.1k", `2014` = "11.9k", `2015` = "12.6k", `2016` = "13.4k", 
`2017` = "14.2k", `2018` = "15.1k", `2019` = "16k", `2020` = "16.3k"), 
row.names = 33L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What I really don't understand is the input. Shouldn't the original dataframe be included somewhere? china_income_30

Comment: The question did not assign the dput output to a variable so the answer called it dat.

Comment: Oh, I see, interesting. It's as if you are doing some sort of in place transformation. I edited that. Forgot to make that adjustment.

Comment: It does not overwrite the input.  The output of the pipeline is the new data frame; you can assign it to save it.

Comment: Just found out while testing in RStudio. When I first read, it didn't occur to me that what I was seeing had to be assigned to a variable.